# How to check is there any date between two dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok, so I have a date when feeding started:

- `**vm.feedFreqDate = 2020-07-06**`

and date when something is created, it's vm.createdDate

```
**vm.createdDate = 2020-07-01**
```

Is there any function i can check if there is other **vm.feedFreqDate** between them?
Sorry for lack of code

Comment: If it's just comparing pairs of uniform date strings, you may simply use  combination of `<`, `>` to compare those and `&&` to combine logical conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the `Date` constructor to parse your data format into timestamp, so you could easily just compare numbers instead.

```js
const startDate = "2020-07-01"
const endDate = "2020-07-06"

function isBetween(start, end, date){
  const startTimestamp = new Date(start).getTime();
  const endTimestamp = new Date(end).getTime();
  const dateTimestamp = new Date(date).getTime();

  return startTimestamp < dateTimestamp && endTimestamp > dateTimestamp;
}


console.log(isBetween(startDate, endDate, "2020-06-06")) // before, expected false
console.log(isBetween(startDate, endDate, "2020-07-03")) // between, expected true
console.log(isBetween(startDate, endDate, "2020-08-01")) // after, expected false
```